# How to stop the wp_mail function?

Tags: wp-mail

I'm using wp_mail filter function.

`add_filter('wp_mail','check_the_mail_content');`

If my condition satisfied then the mail should go, otherwise I need to stop, my function is

```
add_filter('wp_mail','check_the_mail_content');
function check_the_mail_content($query){
    if(mycondition){
         //mail should go.
    }
    else{
        //stop the mail.
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter `'phpmailer_init'`, not `'wp_mail'`. To prevent sending the mail out reset the PHPMailer object.

*Prototype (not tested):*

```
add_action( 'phpmailer_init', 'wpse_53612_conditional_mail_stop' );

function wpse_53612_conditional_mail_stop( $phpmailer )
{
    ! my_condition() and $phpmailer = new stdClass;
}
```

Comment: The `wp_mail()` function is built to catch exceptions of a particular type ... are you sure calling `$phpmailer->Send()` on an object of type `stdClass` won't explode?

Comment: @EAMann The `try {} catch {}` block should prevent that.

Comment: @toscho Good to know. I'm used to `catch(type){}` only catching exceptions of that type ... glad to know PHP is a bit more flexible than that.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, that particular filter isn't verified after it's used.  Here is the use of that filter in core:

```
extract( apply_filters( 'wp_mail', compact( 'to', 'subject', 'message', 'headers', 'attachments' ) ) );
```

So all that filter does is populate the `$to`, `$subject`, `$message`, `$headers`, and `$attechments` varaibles.  It's not an action hook, so while you probably *could* throw some kind of termination operation in there, you really shouldn't.  Ideally, you'd be able to return `false` from your filtering function to kill operation, but the function isn't set up that way.

Instead, I recommend hooking to the `phpmailer_init` action.  It's the last action in the `wp_mail()` function and it passes a reference to the actual `$phpmailer` object that does the mailing.

This ***untested*** function should prevent mail from sending:

```
class fakemailer {
    public function Send() {
        throw new phpmailerException( 'Cancelling mail' );
    }
}

if ( ! class_exists( 'phpmailerException' ) ) :
class phpmailerException extends Exception {
    public function errorMessage() {
        $errorMsg = '<strong>' . $this->getMessage() . "</strong><br />\n";
        return $errorMsg;
    }
}
endif;

add_action( 'phpmailer_init', 'wpse_53612_fakemailer' );
function wpse_53612_fakemailer( $phpmailer ) {
    if ( ! /* condition */ ) 
        $phpmailer = new fakemailer();
}
```

This *should* replace the `$phpmailer` object with an instance of your fake mailer class.  This fake class only contains a `Send()` method that immediately throws an exception of type `phpmailerException`.  The `wp_mail()` function will catch this exception and return `false` by default.

Not the most performant solution in the world ... you should really be checking conditions before even calling `wp_mail()` (as suggested by @Zaidar), but if you must use a hook, this is one way to do it.

Comment: Hi EAMann, Thanks for your answer with clear explanations. It's works. Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 3):

Rather than hooking on `phpmailer_init`, why not just set `$query['to'] = '';` and `return $query;` inside the `wp_mail` hook?

Answer (score 3):

//dont work for me: 
`$phpmailer = new stdClass;`

//for stop wp_mail function use: 
`function my_action( $phpmailer )
{
    if( condition )
    {
        $phpmailer->ClearAllRecipients();
    }
}
add_action( 'phpmailer_init', 'my_action' );`

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using the `wp_mail` filter by returning an empty message. WordPress will not send the email.

```
add_filter('wp_mail','check_the_mail_content');

function check_the_mail_content($args){
 if(!mycondition){ 
  $args["message"]="";//Don't send the email
 }
 return $args;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if(mycondition){
    wp_mail(themail@youwant, $subject, $message)
}else{
    // NOTHING SPECIAL
}
```

Comment: Hi, Zaidar, Thanks for the answer. But the code have some problem, if condition is satisfied then the wp_mail filter called again and again since we called wp_mail again.